# How to determine if a date range overlaps any part of a specific month?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The questions is this.

I want to have the list of all the performances that ran in November 1999. It doesn't matter if the engagements started before November or ended after November.

Table for Engagements is EA_Engagements and the field names are

- StartDate
- EndDate

They are both in DATE form.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site is for "please help me fix..." type questions, not "please write the whole thing for me".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * 
from EA_Engagements 
where StartDate <= '1999-11-30' 
  and EndDate   >= '1999-11-01'
```

Comment: This would only give me engagements that started or ended in November. right?

I need engagements that were **IN** November. They could have started in October or ended in Decemeber.

Comment: make a test!!!!, that is exactly what it returns "the engagements that were IN November".  Read carfuly "start" is checked against last day of november and "end" is checked against first day of november. it is the "natural" way. any two dates (end and start) outside november (or in november), do match que criteria

Comment: When I do that I get an error :(


use willkara; SELECT * FROM EA_Engagements 
WHERE StartDate <= 1999-11-30'   and EndDate   => '1999-11-01';



It says it's on line 2.

Sorry, I've finished every part of this assignment except this.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> '1999-11-01'' at line 2

INNODB

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5066/discussion-between-willkara-and-luis-siquot)

Answer (score 0):

Answer by 'Nedret Recep' worked in my case with similar but different scenario. I wanted to find whether a given daterange is overlapping any other events daterange in the database.

```
Table (Master Blocking Dates)
mbd_id  mbd_from_date   mbd_to_date mbd_reason
1   2013-10-16  2013-10-19  Demo Blocking 1
2   2013-10-21  2013-10-24  Demo2
3   2013-10-31  2013-11-04  Demo3
```

and my query based on 'Nedret Recep' suggestion was this -

```
SELECT * FROM ib_master_blocked_dates WHERE venue_id=$venue_id AND 
(
    (mbd_from_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') 
        OR
    (mbd_to_date BETWEEN  '$from_date' AND '$to_date')
        OR
    ('$to_date' BETWEEN mbd_from_date AND mbd_to_date)
        OR
    ('$from_date' BETWEEN mbd_from_date AND mbd_to_date)
)
```

Result:

```
mbd_id  mbd_from_date   mbd_to_date mbd_reason
1   2013-10-16  2013-10-19  Demo Blocking 1
2   2013-10-21  2013-10-24  Demo2
```

Answer (score -1):

here it is:

```
SELECT
    name, StartDate, EndDate
FROM
    EA_Engagements
WHERE
    StartDate BETWEEN '1999-11-01' AND '1999-11-30' OR
    Enddate BETWEEN  '1999-11-01' AND '1999-11-30'
```

Comment: This won't work for date ranges with a start date before and an end date after the specified month.